# In F# how do I call a constructor with an overload picked based on whether some option values are empty or not?

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#

**Summary**

I want to instantiate a class by only assigning some named parameters dynamically. I want to do this based on whether or not some values are `None`.

So something that looks like this:

```ml
new PhotoEditInput(id=id, title=titleOpt, slug=slugOpt, description=descrOpt, origImageHash=hashStrOpt)
```

`PhotoEditInput`'s constructor has 64 overloads because it can take any of 6 parameters while leaving the others unassigned. So the constructor can be called from `new PhotoEditInput()` with no params at all, to `new PhotoEditInput(id: string, slug: string, title: string, description: string, orderindex: string, origImageHash: string)` with all params assigned, and anything in between.

Each of the `xOpt` values is an `option` and I want to leave `None`s unassigned. So e.g. if `titleOpt` is `None` then I don't want to assign the `title` named parameter.

**Question:** How can I assign these named variables or pick a specific overload dynamically?

---

**Background**

I am using `GraphQLProvider` to generate queries and mutations. I want to create a function that lets a user edit any field of a `photo` object while leaving all the others unchanged.

So for the optional fields in the below function if they are `None` I don't want to change that field in photo with ID `id`. I only want the `Some` values changed.

```ml
let changePhotoFields (id : string) (titleOpt : string option) (slugOpt : string option) (descrOpt : string option) (hashOpt : string option) =
  // function body
```

`PhotoEditInput` is an alias for `GraphQlClient.Types.Photos_set_input`, which is a type generated by `GraphQLProvider` that represents the input of changes to a `photo` entity.

I initially tried instantiating the class with an empty constructor and assigning the fields afterwards but F# won't let me do this. Probably because they are `Option<string> with get` so I assume that means they are not settable? I'm not so familiar with the .NET ecosystem.

```ml
let makeNewPhotoEditInput id titleOpt slugOpt descrOpt hashOpt =
    let input = new PhotoEditInput(id=id)

    input.Title <- titleOpt        // Property 'Title' cannot be set
    input.Slug <- slugOpt          // Property 'Slug' cannot be set
    input.Description <- descrOpt  // Property 'Description' cannot be set
    input.OrigImageHash <- hashOpt // Property 'OrigImageHash' cannot be set

    input
```

If I can get this way to work that would probably be the simplest option. **Is there a way I can set these fields despite them not having setters?**

---

I'm now trying to assign fields conditionally using named arguments. E.g. something like this:

```ml
new PhotoEditInput(id=id, title=titleOpt, slug=slugOpt, description=descrOpt, origImageHash=hashOpt)
```

However this doesn't work because title, slug, and the other args are strings, not string options.

I've also tried making them `string`s but nullable so that F# doesn't complain about the types, but that breaks at runtime.

```ml
let toNull = function Some x -> x | _ -> null

new PhotoEditInput(id=id, title=toNull titleOpt, slug=toNull slugOpt, description=toNull descrOpt, origImageHash=toNull hashOpt)
```

Apparently the constructor can't handle nulls – even though presumably not assigning an argument is no worse than just making it `null` ‍♂️.

So the question is: how can I dynamically choose a specific overload that only assigns fields that are non-null?

In JS if a function supported (the equivalent of) named arguments you'd do something like

```js
new PhotoEditInput({ id: id, title: titleOpt ?? undefined, slug: slugOpt ?? undefined, description: descrOpt ?? undefined, origImageHash: hashOpt?? undefined })
```

is there an equivalent in F#? Perhaps with some of F#'s introspection magic? If so how would I do this?

---

**EDIT in response to @CaringDev's answer:**

It looks like the constructor *does* take 64 overloads. You can pass each parameter individually. I'd imagine that the only way to differentiate between them is by naming the parameter you're assigning, e.g. `new PhotoEditInput(id=id)`.

[image]
[image]

Maybe the fact that it's a generated type means it can do things that you can't do with regular classes, I don't know. Either way your way won't work unfortunately.

In addition to that I'm also getting a warning that `This downcast will erase the provided type 'PhotoEditInput' to the type 'RecordBase'`.

Comment: Did you try and see what happens when you call the ``PhotoEditInput`` constructor with some values that are ``None``? As far as I understand what you wrote, this shouldn't make a difference because the default value for all these parameters is ``None`` anyway.

Comment: Wow, that is some mighty poor API. Essentially whoever designed `PhotoEditInput` went an extra mile making sure that you have to know which parameters are available at compile time.

Comment: @dumetrulo I can't actually pass `None`s because the parameters are all `strings`, not `string options`. However I did try converting options to nullable values. See my example using `toNull`. It threw a runtime error.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it's generated code from `GraphQLProvider` so no one designed that class directly, but yes it does seem odd that it allows me to omit parameters, but won't let me set them to null without crashing.

Comment: @Aron In that case your question needs correcton because there you say the constructor takes ``Option<string>`` values. If passing nulls to the constructor doesn't work, you'll have no choice but to implement a giant match expression that will call the correct overload based on which parameters are ``None``, and which are not.

Comment: @dumetrulo the fields in the instantiated object are options, but the constructor takes strings, not options

Comment: This really makes the case for hand-written API wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

If the `PhotoEditInput` type was a type with a constructor taking optional parameters, then you should be able to pass `option` values to those optional arguments (automatically mapping `None` to a missing value) using the following syntax:

```
new PhotoEditInput(id=id, ?title=titleOpt, 
       ?slug=slugOpt, ?description=descrOpt, ?origImageHash=hashStrOpt)
```

I'm not sure if this works with the type provider generated type that you are using (as I have no easy way of testing that), but this certainly works with normal types:

```
type Demo(id:string, ?n:int) = 
  override x.ToString() = sprintf "%s %A" id n

let opt = if 1=1 then Some 123 else None
Demo("123", ?n=opt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I get error `FS0193 Type constraint mismatch. The type 'string option' is not compatible with type 'string'`. It seems that the compiler just ignores the `?` in `?param` for some reason and still thinks it should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Both in F# `Duplicate method. The method '.ctor' has the same name and signature as another method in type 'Foo'.`

```
type Foo() =
    new(a : string) = Foo() 
    new(b : string) = Foo()
```

and C# `CS0111 Type 'Foo' already defines a member called 'Foo' with the same parameter types`

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {}
    public Foo(string a) {}
    public Foo(string b) {}
}
```

as parameter *names* are not part of the signature. So I doubt that there are 64 overloads... if they look like this however:

```
type Foo() =
    new(a : string) =
        printfn "a"
        Foo()
    new(a : string, b : string) =
        printfn "b"
        Foo()
    new(a : string, b : string, c : string) =
        printfn "c"
        Foo()
```

the following works, given that the parameter order is correct and you don't need to set parameters that come *after* others:

```
let parameters =
    [ Some "a"; None; Some "c" ] // c will be ignored
    |> Seq.takeWhile Option.isSome
    |> Seq.choose (Option.map(fun s -> s :> obj))
    |> Array.ofSeq

Activator.CreateInstance(typeof<Foo>, parameters) :?> Foo // prints 'a'
```

Comment: Hi @CaringDev, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply! See my question edit, but unfortunately your way still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Aron thanks for your edit... that looks 'interesting' :-) Any chance you can share a minimal, reproducible example, e.g. on github? Even if not, I‘ll have another look tomorrow.

Comment: @Aron could you provide (a subset of) your introspection json and the GraphQLProvider instantiation?